# How to delete selected row from datagridview and database?

Tags: c#-to-vb.net

Iam a beginner in c#,Iam able to delete it from datagridview​ but not from database, Please help me.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "row index" in a relational database.

Comment: What iam trying to do is to select a particular row from datagridview and then to delete it from data base,how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You'll need to create a connection to the database
2. You'll need to bind the result from the query to the datagridview using a `commandBuilder` and a `Bindingsource`, this will enable you to automatically execute the delete statement by just pressing delete.

See a detailed tutorial at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control